# After publish IAP Google play get response 3 : billing unavailable

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, google-play

I already upload yg .apk in Google Developer Console and add my tester account. I'm publish in alpha tab.

This is my AndroidManifest.XML

```
<!--all-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!--Google Play-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<!--Open Store-->
<uses-permission android:name="org.onepf.openiab.permission.BILLING" />
<!--Amazon requires no permissions -->
<!--Samsung Apps-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.iap.permission.BILLING" />
<!--Nokia-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.nokia.payment.BILLING"/>
<!--SlideME-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.slideme.sam.manager.inapp.permission.BILLING" />
```

If i download n install from Google Play, i get tester version and everything work fine. but if i install apk from my external sd card. i get response 3: billing unavailable. why i got difference return?

if there a little change in my apk and i like to testing. do i have to publish my new apk again in google play every time i change my code?

Answer (score 1):

The Play Store In-app purchase flow will work only if you keep the following exactly the same as the latest apk uploaded

1. Bundle ID (com.company.product)
2. Bundle version (eg: 1.0.1)
3. Bundle version code (eg: 1)

So, say for example, you have an apk uploaded that has a bundle version of 1.0.1 and you install an apk that has a bundle version of 1.0.2 from your SD card, you will get this error.

Also, check if you're signed in with a tester account on your device, one that you have also added in the Alpha / Beta channel in the Play Store console.

The easiest way to test is to upload a version of the app, set up all your SKUs (seems like you've already done that), and then never change the version code or number of your apk while testing.

Once you're satisfied with the results of your testing, you can then upload a new version.

Comment: hmmm....
Well that strange, i install the same apk that i upload in google developer console, but get different result